# livewire component and blade still detected even when i already remove it

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i am trying to delete some livewire blade and component with
`php artisan livewire:delete showcase`
and then in the routing(`web.php`) i connect it with the one in the controller (ShowcaseController), but when i load the page, its still asking the blade from livewire (`Showcase.blade.php`) instead the blade that i made outside livewire folder (the one that has been deleted).
does anyone know how to solve this or remove livewire blade and component that has been made safely? im using laravel 8 and livewire 2
thank you

showcase routing code

```
//------------------Controller Showcase------------------//
use App\Http\Controllers\ShowcaseController;
Route::get('/showcase',  [ShowcaseController::class, 'index'])->name("showcase");
```

showcase controller code

```
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();

        return view('Showcase.showcase', [
            'products' => $products,

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share/attach the error.

Comment: ah right sorry, the error are Target class [App\Http\Livewire\Showcase] does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

all done guys i just put the blade.php outside view folder, all done, sorry for my clumsy still learning new thing haha